# Gradle dependency exclusion not working

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

My project `build.gradle` dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'

    compile 'co.realtime:messaging-android:2.1.58'
}
```

And the **co.realtime:messageing-android** [build.gradle](https://github.com/realtime-framework/RealtimeMessaging-Android/blob/2.1.58/library/build.gradle) dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'){
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'){
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile ('com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'){
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

If I try to compile my project I get the following error:

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task
>   ':app-module:processProdDebugResources'.
>   Error: more than one library with package name 'com.google.android.gms'   You can temporarily disable this error with
>   android.enforceUniquePackageName=false   However, this is temporary
>   and will be enforced in 1.0

If I use `enforceUniquePackageName(false)` I get:

> cannot resolve symbol to `GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE`

So I guess I'll have to solve this by managing the dependencies. I've tried:

```
compile ('co.realtime:messaging-android:2.1.58'){
        exclude module: 'com.google'
}

compile ('co.realtime:messaging-android:2.1.58'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-gcm'
}
```

But nothing seams to work... How can I solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in 'play-services-gcm' instead of 'play-services'

```
compile ('co.realtime:messaging-android:2.1.58'){
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
}
```

grrr those typo mistakes... Well I thought I could delete this question but, once in a while someone has the same issue, so I will leave this here hoping perhaps it helps someone in need.